# Prime factorization of $x + 1$ given prime decomposition of $x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

Suppose you had the prime factorization of $x = \prod_{k=1}^m p_k$. Are there any algorithms for deciding the prime factorization of $x + 1$? Are their prime factorizations related in any way at all?

EDIT: It's known that $x$ and $x + 1$ are coprime. That means that you get *some* amount of information about the prime factors of $x + 1$. Can the information about prime factors of $x$ be used to figure out the prime factors of $x + 1$ *faster* than just "prime sieve" + "filter out the factors of $x$"?

Comment: To that second part: $p \mid x \implies p \nmid x+1$, and $p \mid x+1 \implies p \nmid x$.  I don't know if you can say much more than that, though

Comment: Since $a\implies \lnot b$ is equivalent to $b\implies \lnot a$, those two conditions are really one. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @ThomasAndrews whoops.  Well, that's all right

Comment: Nothing at all. $x$ and $x+1$ are coprime.

Comment: Sure, they're co-prime (assuming x > 1). But can we say *anything* about the prime factors of $x + 1$, beyond that they're not factors of $x$?

Comment: Just one of them is even and the other odd. Nothing more.In particulat $x$ can have many factors and $x+1$ can be prime.

Comment: So you are looking for primes p where x = -1 mod(p)? You could come up with some vague conditions on p...

Comment: In general, there is no relation between the prime factors of $x$ and those of $x+1$, except the trivial fact that $x$ and $x+1$ share no prime factor, and if $x\equiv -1 \mod p$, then $p|x+1$. If a general method were known, the factorization of the fermat numbers or the proth numbers or mor generally, every number of the form $s+1$ where $s$ can easily be factored could be easily factored as well.

Comment: In fact, factorization would be an easy task for most numbers because it can be expected that for most numbers there is a number "not much smaller" which can easily be completely factored. Once, we have found such a number, we could easily factor the given number. We could not manage all numbers in practice, but we could factor many extremely difficult cases

Comment: I think a simple look at a table of multiplication (available on google) will tell you that there is no relation between factors of x and those of x+1. if you take any number in that table and look at the numbers that are smaller but on the same vertical line than x, you will never find x-1. Now if you look at the numbers to the left of x but on the horizontal line, you will never see x-1 among them. This simply means x and x-1 cannot share a factor.

Comment: the numbers that can help us factor x are those which share the same p+q or p-q. Unfortunately, determining what those numbers are is as hard as factoring x.